# Android, How to add ScrollView into screen which has some list items?

Tags: android, scrollview

in my activity, i have three lists. after running the application, the screen is not scroll-able. i can scroll the list which is on top of others but i can't scroll the whole of page. I tried to add `ScrollView` into my xml layout but lint says that "The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)".

How to make my screen scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/GlobalLayout" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView1"
                  android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                  android:layout_height="100dip"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
       <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView2"
                  android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                  android:layout_height="100dip"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
       <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView3"
                  android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                  android:layout_height="100dip"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you, i did this but result was same, i couldn't scroll the screen.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Scrollview supports one child layout so make the listview inside  the scroll so you will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you, i did this but result was same, i couldn't scroll the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because android don't know with which view he should scroll, so putting a `listview` in a `scrollview` its not a bright idea.
try to use `visibilty` attribute, use to `HIDE` the view that you finich to work with and set `VISIBLE` the new.
or use one `ListView` and try to populate and remove items after finishing and starting an instruction.
hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can add header and footer into your list view by inflating them. Create three xml layououts and add them in listview using header and footer.

```
    View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

use it before setting adapter. lv is listview.