# Android display two full-size ListViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am unable to display two sequential full-sized (in height) `ListViews` that would not be scrollable individually but only by scrolling the root element.

This thing is haunting me all day long since I had various outputs (two scrollable list views, half-cut scrollview, etc) but none succeeded. Read previous posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496804/android-how-to-add-scrollview-into-screen-which-has-some-list-items) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android).

Providing you the current layout xml, what could be the solution? Removal of `ScrollView`, changing `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, setting `layout_weight`?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner
                android:id="@+id/ad_list_filter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                />

            <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner
                android:id="@+id/ad_list_sort"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/adListInterests"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            >
        </ListView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ad_list_seperator"
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/adListNoninterests"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

After removing the suggested `ScrollView` results in two scrollable lists. According to comments, I will try to achieve it by using the provided plugins, however I still hope for finding solution based on modifying layout code only. Thank you for your time!

Image:

[image: Preview]

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ad_list_filter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />

        <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner
            android:id="@+id/ad_list_sort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/adListInterests"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ad_list_seperator"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/adListNoninterests"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `Removal of ScrollView` is **highly recommended** (it's really a **worse practice**). What does this `ListViews that would not be scrollable individually but only by scrolling the root element` mean? Maybe, you can rethink your UI to use an `ExpandableListView` (parent/children relation)?

Comment: @DerGolem just wanted to say that the lists should be fully shown and scrolling must happen on ScrollView.

Comment: Are you aware that putting ListViews (or any other **scrollable**) inside a ScrollView (or any other **scrollable**) is a **BAD** idea?

Comment: Yes. That is so because of the 'confusion' of which View to use - `ScrollView` or `ListView` when the scroll event is trigerred.

Comment: Yes, there's a "conflict" in scrolling. I also think there's a certain CPU overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea about having two separate `ListView` was wrong - instead of that I built a single `ListView` and added a custom row as header for the following list after the first one has ended.

The concept I used is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers).

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy is right, just change your `ListView`s code like this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- cahnge this line -->
android:layout_weight="xxx" <!-- remove this line -->
```

However this is a poor, inefficient and memory hogging solution. By doing this you are forcing all the views off screen to remain in memory. A better solution would be to use only one list with custom adapter handling multiple datasets/viewtypes and a header view containing the spinners.

The easiest and quickest and most correct solution for you right now would be using the [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) library which allows you to load one `ListView` with data from mulitple `ListAdapter`s. Once you understand how it works and use it, you can change layout like so:

**list_header.xml**

You'll have to set the header view programmatically before you assign the merge adapter to the list view. You can inflate this layout XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner.../>
  <xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MultiSpinner.../>
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_main.xml**

This is the main layout of your activity or fragment. It will contain just the list, which can handle everything you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adListInterests"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"/>
```

**How to use cwac-merge**

You'll need to import it in Gradle (for Android Studio)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.1.+'
}
```

or download a couple of `.jar`s (for Eclipse)

- https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/releases
- https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist/releases

This is how the code will look:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_header, null, false);

// get references for your Spinners here...

myListView.addHeader(header, null, false);

// setup your two adapters as you are doing now

MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addAdapter(firstAdapter); // the adapter that you previously used for the first list
adapter.addAdapter(secondAdapter); // the adapter that you previously used for the second list
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but could I achieve by not using any library? Just refactoring the code?

Comment: Why not use the library? It's distributed as a `.jar` sou you can easily import it to Android Studio and Eclipse. I updated the answer on how to use it, it's really chort piece of code. In any case you should copy the layout from my answer and if you're not using the library you'll have to implement custom `BaseAdapter`.